# Disable paging in GridView to Excel export

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've got a function to export some data from the `GridView` to Excel, which is bound to some checkboxes. So it only exports the rows that are checked.
This works fine, however I can't seem to disable paging for the export?
This is my code:

```
 private void ExportGridToExcel()
{

    bool isSelected = false;
    foreach (GridViewRow i in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)i.FindControl("chkSelect");
        if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
        {
            isSelected = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isSelected)
    {
        GridView gvExport = GridView1;
        // this below line for not export checkbox to excel file
        gvExport.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        foreach (GridViewRow i in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            gvExport.Rows[i.RowIndex].Visible = false;
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)i.FindControl("chkSelect");
            if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
            {
                gvExport.Rows[i.RowIndex].Visible = true;
            }
        }

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExportGridData.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htW = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
        Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        gvExport.AllowPaging = false;
        gvExport.RenderControl(htW);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();

    }
}

protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ExportGridToExcel();

}
```

As you can see I've set `AllowPaging = false` but the page numbers are still visible in the exported file. Anybody got any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

To export the whole data from your GridView you have to re-bind the Datasource

```
//1.bind with paging disabled
gvExport.AllowPaging = false;
gvExport.DataBind();

//2.export method here

//3.bind with paging enabled
gvExport.AllowPaging = true;
gvExport.DataBind();
```

but if it's possible i would export the data directly from the datasource because you have to remove headers, hide columns, replace `&nbsp;` and handle controls like `asp:Checkbox` seperately

This is a good approach if you want to export from your `asop:GridView` - http://forums.asp.net/post/4222334.aspx

Comment: Yeah it works when I do the DataBind however I'm trying to only export the data with the checkbox checked so when I do the DataBind that functionality is lost

Comment: but the `checked` value is stored in the database? so you can export `db.YourData.Where(x => x.export)` or sth?

Answer (score 0):

Before rendering - disable the paging, bind the data and then render:

```
gvExport.AllowPaging = false;
gvExport.DataSource = ds; //Data Source
gvExport.DataBind();
gvExport.RenderControl(objHtmlTextWriter)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code block below is operational.

```cs
GridView2.AllowPaging = false;
GridView2.DataSource = GetProducts(); //Data Source
GridView2.DataBind();
GridView2.RenderControl(htw);
```

[image]